# dropdown change list value when I choose a different value of list in other dropdown with angular 5

Tags: angular5

I want to build a test about component in angular 5 about dropdown.
When I choose a different value in list dropdown (dropdown1), the list in other dropdown (dropdown2) changes.
For exemple:
I have two Object:

```
Country = [{id:1, name:'USA'}, {id:2, name:'France'}];
City = [{id:1, name:'Chicago', countryId:1}, {id:2, name:'New York', countryId:1}, {id:3, name:'Texas', countryId:1}, {id:4, name:'Paris', countryId:2}, {id:5, name:'Toulouse', countryId:2}];
```

In view, when I select USA country in dropdown, an other dropdown display a list of City of USA. Same for France.

Please help me, thank you very much

Answer (score -1):

Please check this sample project. This will help you,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-heokyk

The logic is, create a dropdown with list of countries and upon selecting, we need to find the cities by country id. Once you get that list, render the second dropdown with that list.

To get the callback back on select the countries, you can use (change) event in the dropdown

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20952646)

Comment: @trollster Thanks for the review. I will edit the answer accordingly

Comment: @trollster Please review

Comment: @trollster Please review my answer.